# Veins tutorial over MacOS

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I have successfully installed Veins (v5.1), SUMO (v1.9.1) and OMNeT++ (v5.6.2) in macOS Big Sur. OMNeT++ and SUMO work perfectly when running alone. Also the erlangen example ends correctly when launching "sumo-gui  -c erlangen.s.sumo.cfg"

However, when I try to run the Veins demo scenario, I get the following error by SUMO:

"Error:Storage::readChar():invalid position".

The veins_launchd listens correctly on port 9999, SUMO loads successfully all the configuration files, but upon starting the simulation it terminates with the above error (also reported [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBE0y.png)).

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upgrade SUMO to at least SUMO 1.9.2 or downgrade SUMO to SUMO 1.8.

SUMO 1.9.1 had a bug that broke TraCI functionality. More details are available on https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/pull/8601

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Everything runs perfectly after upgrading SUMO to v1.9.2. Thank you again!